# Why does MongoDB give a response stating the document has been updated, but no update it made?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can't figure this out.
I have an object in an array within another object which I need to update with mongoDB updateOne.

I make the call, it says it found it OK and has updated it ({ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }). But then on checking no update is made in the database...

What am I doing wrong here?

**Model**

```
const pathwayDetailsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
associatedPathwayID: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
},
pages: [
   {
    _id: { type: String },
    x: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    y: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    widgets: [
        {
            more nested objects..
        }
    ]
 }
]
}
```

**Router call**

```
router.post('/pageupdate/',auth, async(req,res)=>{
const pageID = req.body.pageID; //Page ID string
const pathwayID = req.body.pathwayID; // pathwayID string
const update = req.body.update; //{x: new X value, y: new Y value}
try{
    console.log("receieved: ",pageID, pathwayID, update);
    let updatedDoc = await PathwayDetails.updateOne(
        { associatedPathwayID: pathwayID, "pages._id": pageID },
        { $set: update}
        );
    console.log("successful? ",updatedDoc)
    res.status(201).send(updatedDoc)
}
catch(e){
    etc...
}
```

});

Changing x and y passes through fine and it says it updates. But on checking the database no change is made...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed `async` keyword before `await`.
A function should be an `async` inorder to use the `await` keyword.
So, you wrap the code inside a `async` function.

Since you are not using the async function, await has lost it's functionality, so it's basically updating the old value again and again. It's not awaiting fo the new value. So you are not seeing any change in the value in the database even though the code is executed successfully.

Try the below code:

```
const update_document = async (req, res) => {
  let updatedDoc = await PathwayDetails.updateOne(
        { associatedPathwayID: pathwayID, "pages._id": pageID },
        { $set: update}
        );
    res.status(201).send(updatedDoc)
};
```

After this call the `update_document` function with the router.

I think this will work.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I just didn't include all the code in there. It is inside an async function.

Comment: Can you share the complete code including the function ?

Comment: Just updated. Sorry should have added the whole block.
If I was missing the async then it definitely wouldn't have returned with a success response!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The update I was passing wasn't pointing to a nested object correctly.

Rather than update being {x: new X value, y: new Y value}

needed to pass a nested update it must be {"pages.$.x": new X value, "pages.$.y": new Y value}

It is annoying that mongo returns a response saying it has updated the database when it can't find the field to update!